# Modules over PIDs in Algebra by Grove

Tags: abstract-algebra

Working through Algebra by Grove, I am in the section of defining modules over PID's. So we are assuming R is a PID for this. I am having issues understanding proposition 3.5 is chapter 4, section 3, page 136. It states,

Suppose $M=R\langle y\rangle$ is cyclic of order $r$, and $s \in R$. Then, 
$$(i)\;\; M[s]=R\langle (r/(r,s))y\rangle \simeq R/(r,s),$$ $$(ii)\;\; sM=R\langle (r,s)y \rangle \simeq R/(r/(r,s)),$$ 
so $M[s]$ is cyclic of order $(r,s)$ and $sM$ is cyclic of order $r/(r,s)$.

In the paragraph before this, it states that $(r,s)$ refers to both the ideal generated by $\lbrace r,s \rbrace$ and the GCD of r and s. As this is an abuse of notation, I am having difficulties interpreting how $M[s]$ and $sM$ are being defined in $(i)$ and $(ii)$. I know that $r$ is a number since its the order of $M$, but $s$ might not be a number since $R$ is general, so how do we reconcile $(r,s)$ in either case.

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! There is a problem with these notations: *a priori*, $\;\bigl(r//(r,s)\bigr)$ is meaningless since we have $(r)\subset (r,s)$, not the reverse inclusion. Unless  it means the ideal generated  by the quotient of $r$ by $\gcd(r,s)$?

Comment: The book specifically states that it is mixing the use of $(r,s)$ as both the ideal generated by $r$ and $s$, and as gcd$(r,s)$, but doesn't specify when it uses one or the other. I would have to assume that they mean the ideal generated by the quotient of $r$ by gcd$(r,s)$. But I'm struggling to understand how that works.

Comment: How is $M[s]$ defined  ?

Comment: $M[s]$ is defined as $\lbrace x\in M:sx=0 \rbrace$

Answer (score 1):

Here '$M=R\langle y\rangle$ is a cyclic module of order $r$' means that it is generated by a single element $y$ and $r\in R$ is the generator of its annihilator $\{u\in R:uy=0\}\, \trianglelefteq R$, an *element of $R$*.

Then in both definitions $(r,s)$ is used as gcd (the generator of their generated ideal).

As for $M[s]$, it is a strange notation. It usually indicates to adjoin an external element. However, in this context, as mentioned in the comments, it denotes the submodule $\{m\in M:sm=0\}$.

Comment: Thank you! I had mixed up order in the context of modules and in the context of cyclic groups. It makes a lot more sense viewing $r$ as the annihilator.